# Why 'all' function in Python receives array instead of *args?

Tags: python

the question is about popular Pythonic function all.

```
a = True
b = True
print(all([a, b]))
```

Why not to use `*args` ? So it will look like this:

```
a = True
b = True
print(all(a, b))
```

List seems redundant here - when we have the ability to pass arguments to *args.

Comment: Is your question why a function that is designed to check each element of iterables requires an iterable as argument? That kinda answers itself.

Comment: That's not an array, that's a list.

Comment: It takes an iterator or iterable object which is a common idiom in python. Among other benefits, the entire collection need not be resident in memory at the same time

Comment: It could be that `all` became a standard part of Python before the `*args` syntax was added.  But that would be many versions in past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`all` is for when you already have an iterable. If you have two individual booleans, that's `and`'s job:

```
print(a and b)
```

Making `all` take `*args` instead of an iterable would force materialization of the input, even in cases where a `False` result could be returned early, or when the input iterable has too many elements to hold all of them in memory.

```
from itertools import repeat

def starargs_all(*booleans):
    return all(booleans)

print(all(repeat(False, 10**10))) # prints immediately
print(starargs_all(*repeat(False, 10**10))) # takes a while, uses lots of memory, awkward *
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `all()` works with **ANY** iterable, not only lists. E.g:

```
def makeGen():
   i = 1
   while i <= 10:
      yield i
      i = i + 1

all(makeGen())
```

Comment: This example is misleading, because `*args` also works with generator objects. Just try `def all2(*args): return all(args)`.

Comment: How it's related to my question ?

Comment: @Markus which would render the point of a generator completely pointless

Comment: You state, that `all()` works with ANY iterable. But isn't this the case for `*args` too?

Comment: @Markus But `*args` is creating a list as does `list(makeGen())`. Are you deliberately trying to missunderstand my answer? `all(*args)` is not working in the same way as `all(iterable)`, these are different things.

Comment: I am completely aware of that. But again you stress the word ANY. This clearly implies that UNLIKE `*args` `all` works with ANY iterable. You are implying that some iterables do not work with `*args`, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Markus *is supposed to work with any without extra work* might be a better  phrasing but to be honest, you are just nitpicking and wasting my time. There is already a code snippet to illustrate the point. As I said, you deliberately want to missunderstand what other people write and I'm totally pissed off by such behaviour. If you are able to understand the snippet, you should be able to understand the answer totally fine! There is no need to be more precise here. Bother somebody else if you want to boost your own ego.

Comment: So I downvote your post for a reason and get a downvote on one of my (1.5 year old!) posts 2 min later. This behaviour disgusts me.